# yii how to simplify check exists then insert

Tags: yii

I'm use Yii 1 to insert data when the data not exists.

```
$email = 'xx@xx';
if( ! people::model()->exists("email = :email", array(':email'=>$email) ){
     $people = new people();
     $people->email = $email;

     $people->xx = xx 
     // ... save
}
```

I want to write like this, It's simplify and quick:

```
$people = new people();
$people->email = $email;
if( ! $people->exists() ){
     $people->xx = xx 
     // ... save
}
```

Dose yii CActiveRecord has way to do this or need I extends CActiveRecord ?

Comment: you can also put logic in your model, `beforeValidate()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii has a limitation on composite unique key validation. check here : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15622-composite-unique-key-validation/
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10154-unique-validator-criteria/

Therefore, i would suggest this way of unique validation.

in rules,

```
array('username', 'validateUniqueUsername'),
```

then the method definition.

```
public function validateUniqueUsername($attribute, $params)
{
    $validator = new CUniqueValidator();
    $validator->attributes = array($attribute);
    $validator->validate($this, array($attribute));
    if ($this->hasErrors($attribute)) {
        $this->clearErrors($attribute);
        $this->addError('username', Yii::t('auth', 'Username "'.$this->username.'" has already been taken.'));
    }
}
```

Ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUniqueValidator

Comment: This will also help you to customize the error message according to your need.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, you can Use [unique](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation/#hh21) validator in your Model rules.

```
public function rules()
{        
    return array(
        array('field1,field2, field3, email, field4', 'required'),
        array('email', 'email','message'=>'Invalid email.'),
        array('email', 'unique', 'message' => 'Email already exists!'),
        ...................
        ...................

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Yii does have an exists method in the CActiveRecord. You simply specify the condition, and call exists(), and your model will return whether or not a record exists satisfying those conditions.

[Yii CActiveRecord exists() method details can be found here.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#exists-detail)

You shouldn't need to extend CActiveRecord outside of the typical way that is done in the definition of a particular model.